# Masonry doesn't work with Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, masonry

My problem is that I can't make Masonry work with my Bootstrap columns (grid).

**Step 1 -** I called for the Masonry in my `<head>` like so :

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.1.5/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

**Step 2 -** I wrote my bootstrap html (this is the part I want to apply Masonry on) :

```html
<div class="row" id="container"> <!-- container begins -->

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6  item"> <!-- 1st column starts -->
                     
                      <div class="well clearfix">

                <section>        
                             <img src="http://placehold.it/410x130" class="img-responsive visible-lg" alt="" style=" margin-bottom: 15px;">              
                              
                             <h2 id="post">This is my wordpress post title</h2>
                       
                        <div class="post-label">
                             <span class="label label-default">Aymen</span>
                             <span class="label label-default">Web Design</span>
                             <span class="label label-default">12-10-2014</span>
                             <span class="label label-default">Comments 24</span>
                        </div>
                    <hr>
                              <p id="post">
                        The Bootstrap 3 grid system has four tiers of classes: xs (phones), sm (tablets), md (desktops), and lg (larger desktops). You can use nearly any combination of these classes to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.
                              </p>
                    <hr>
                             <a href="#"><div class="more">Read More</div></a>
                             <a href="#"><div class="share">Share me</div></a>
                </section>
                      </div> 
            </div> <!-- 1st column ends -->


            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6  item"> <!-- 2nd column starts -->
                     
                      <div class="well clearfix">

                <section>        
                             <img src="http://placehold.it/410x130" class="img-responsive visible-lg" alt="" style=" margin-bottom: 15px;">              
                              
                             <h2 id="post">This is my wordpress post title</h2>
                       
                        <div class="post-label">
                             <span class="label label-default">Aymen</span>
                             <span class="label label-default">Web Design</span>
                             <span class="label label-default">12-10-2014</span>
                             <span class="label label-default">Comments 24</span>
                        </div>
                    <hr>
                              <p id="post">
                        The Bootstrap 3 grid system has four tiers of classes: xs (phones), sm (tablets), md (desktops), and lg (larger desktops). You can use nearly any combination of these classes to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.
                              </p>
                    <hr>
                             <a href="#"><div class="more">Read More</div></a>
                             <a href="#"><div class="share">Share me</div></a>
                </section>
                      </div> 
            </div> <!-- 2nd column ends -->

                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6  item"> <!-- 2nd column starts -->
                     
                      <div class="well clearfix">

                <section>        
                             <img src="http://placehold.it/410x130" class="img-responsive visible-lg" alt="" style=" margin-bottom: 15px;">              
                              
                             <h2 id="post">This is my wordpress post title</h2>
                       
                        <div class="post-label">
                             <span class="label label-default">Aymen</span>
                             <span class="label label-default">Web Design</span>
                             <span class="label label-default">12-10-2014</span>
                             <span class="label label-default">Comments 24</span>
                        </div>
                    <hr>
                              <p id="post">
                        The Bootstrap 3 grid system has four tiers of classes: xs (phones), sm (tablets), md (desktops), and lg (larger desktops). You can use nearly any combination of these classes to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.
                              </p>
                    <hr>
                             <a href="#"><div class="more">Read More</div></a>
                             <a href="#"><div class="share">Share me</div></a>
                </section>
                      </div> 
            </div> <!-- 2nd column ends -->

        </div> <!-- container ends -->
```

**Step 3** - I added the javascript code above `</body>` :

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

**Step 4** I added .item class to `col-lg-3 col-md-6` as yo ucan see in **Step 1**

But nothing happens, the columns don't take their right places as they should.

Comment: Your class hierarchy is wrong. `container` then `row` then `col-*`.

Answer (score 0):

This all works, but since you're using Bootstrap, why are you setting the columns to a fixed width?

I would recommend something like this:

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: '.item',
  itemSelector: '.item'
```

This will use Bootstrap's percentages for column widths (eg. 33.33333% for col-md-4 etc) rather than fixed pixel widths.

And just for the sake of clarity, the HTML needs to look something like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 item">
      Some content
    </div>
    <!--- More columns here as required --->
  </div>
</div>
```